# Shading with two .PNG maps and one object

Tags: node-editor, shaders

I am trying to make some TTS models to play W40K in the lockdowns. The resources I got a hold of has the body and the guns as separate documents. They are saved as .png and I can't seem to make them work together. In addition, the model is transparent so I am certain something was missed.

[image]

Comment: You can combine the two images together using a MixRGB Node. If one image has a transparency (alpha output), connect it as the mix factor.

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/668797339930066965/734901766927155220/unknown.png

Like this?

Comment: It's hard to tell how they're mix without seeing the textures, and how they apply to the model. Any chance you could upload a .blend file? You can do it here  - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=kPEsn516" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/kPEsn516/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for uploading, but you need to pack the textures so I can see them. Go to file > external data > pack all into .blend

Comment: Thanks for the help you gave. Obviously I am not going to be able to grab some pre made resources and learn what I need for this task alone. Found out that the resources I have are designed not to work with blender and a few other problems. Thank you for the help though.

Comment: Hey no problem. Hope you can figure it out. There's still a chance it could work  with blender. If you upload the file with the packed images, I could still give it a shot. I'll explain in detail what I did if I can get it to work.